# Modified mesh loses changes when leaving edit mode

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh

Apologies if this has been asked, but I couldn't find it anywhere. I'm using Blender 2.49b to change some head meshes for Morrowind, and they're already animated. The lips move and the eyes blink. I'm editing the neck, but every time I do and back out of edit mode, the changes revert. I figured the animations had something to do with it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please include a screen image.  Show the mesh and vertex groups and modifiers.  What you have stated above can be improved with more information.

Comment: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/x07n4Ko.png)
sorry about that. hope that's what you needed
this is what it reverts to after i back out to object mode. i had moved the vertices at the bottom of head mesh to line up with the neck

Comment: Any special reasons to use that quite old version of Blender ? Things have changed very much since then, chanses to face a bug in there are much higher.

Comment: i couldn't get blender set up to import nifs on the newer versions and it was driving me crazy. i found a download on the morrowind nexus that had everything i needed

Answer (score 1):

Various Explanations for the behaviour.
Incomplete list follows.

- Shape Keys.  If there are multiple Shape Keys present,  then you may end up editing a shape key whose influence is zero 0 or close to zero. Blinking eyes could be done with various animation techniques including shape keys.
- Modifiers.  Shrink Wrap or Armature modifier can change the mesh shape. That is the purpose of such modifiers.  For example small edits might be completely dominated by a Shrink Wrap Modifier and thus not visible.

Comment: so, its defintely shape keys, but luckily there are only 3 of them. do i need to change the shape for each key?